# Book about implanting minds in new bodies and a young woman who sells her body to an old woman and wakes up in a new one

Tags: story-identification, books, cyborg

I read this book sometime in the early 2000s, and I believe it was published around then too; definitely no later than 2007.

I vaguely remember the cover being minimalist blue with a naked woman's body curled like an embryo. However this was in Australia, so the cover may have been different elsewhere. Or my memory is completely wrong.

I picked this up from the adult sci-fi section in the library, however it may have been YA as I don't remember it being too risque.

Plot points I remember:

- I believe the book is set on a future Earth where the rich live in skyscrapers above the clouds of pollution and the poor live down on the ground below the pollution.
- The MC is a young woman who is poor, living on the ground working in a factory and making just enough to scrape by.
- At the factory where she works there is an explosion and her friend or family member is injured and burned and they don't earn enough to get healed.
- In exchange for her friend being healed, the MC sells her young youthful body to a rich older woman who will inhabit her body and be young and strong again.
- Part of this exchange was that the MC was to be given a basic cyborg? (I say cyborg, but it may be bio-created) body or the old woman's body in return, I can't quite remember.
- The MC's consciousness wakes up in an experimental enhanced body that has an internal AI that communicates with her. I think she also had enhanced senses and strength, and maybe the ability to choose how she looks?
- As the MC now has an enhanced body that can handle space travel she now has the ability to go to space, and as such the book ends with her in space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is [*Spare Parts*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?218533) (1999) by Sally Rogers-Davidson.

[image: Cover of Spare Parts]

The protagonist is named Kelty, and her best friend Mary, is critically injured at an explosion in the recycling plant where they both work.

After the accident, Kelty sells her human body to pay for a transplant for her friend Mary, accepting a cyborg body for herself:

> ‘Very lucky. Unless I’m sadly mistaken, we should be able to arrange a very good deal for you, Miz Holmes. More than enough to pay for a state-of-the-art replacement body.’
>
> Napoleone dropped his hands back down to the desk, but Kelty managed to look him in the face as she asked, ‘And Mary?’
>
> ‘You could make it a part of the deal that the client donate her used body to Mary, and I’m offering to perform her transplant at a generous discount, which should mean you’ll have enough to cover the cost of both transplants.’

As I recall Kelty is *required* to go to space, since cyborgs aren't permitted on Earth.

There's an extensive [excerpt from the book](https://www.sallyrogersdavidson.com/spare-parts-excerpt.html) available on the author's website.

Comment: YES!!! That is it exactly! I am buying it from amazon right now! Thankyou so much for placing it for me. It doesn't surprise me too much my memory is skewed. Now lets see if I still enjoy it :)

Comment: I find it rather hilarious that someone else was plagued by the memory of the same obscure Australian book. I am so happy, you have no idea! It has stuck with me for so many years I was starting to think I made it up.